# Detect Particle System based particles within a radius and get their position

Tags: unity

I am working on a feature where I want to detect particle system-based crops within a certain radius of my harvester. I have tried **OverlapSphere** but seems like Unity doesn't detect particle systems through raycast or any type of casting.

Few forums say that try getting all particles and check those particles that are closest but the problem is that this will get overwhelming since I have up to 20k particles spawned and each frame traversing all particles to check which particles are within a radius does not seems like a good idea since harvester will be moving.

Need opinions here since I haven't yet found a proper solution.

[image]

[image: particle system collision setting]

Comment: You could assign the particles to indices based on grid coordinates, then simply check all indices that match grid coordinates overlapped by your circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding properly, but it sounds like you have `GameObjects` with particle emitters that render the individual meshes making up the crops?

Since individual particles in an emitter aren't tracked with the same fidelity as other collision systems (for performance reasons), it may be worth attempting a solution like this:

> **Note:** I don't have a lot of experience with customizing particle emitters, but hopefully some API exploration can net you results using this high-level approach.

---

#### A

1. Ensure each crop tile contains a collider covering the particle emission area.

   - Optionally split the colliders (and emitters) into a grid on top of your crop tile to improve performance.
   - Optionally sleep/disable colliders belonging to crop tiles far away from the player to aid in performance.
2. If your OverlapSphere intersects with a crop tile, GOTO B.

#### B

- If you have a single collider per crop tile, iterate through each particle in the appropriate emitter, compare its position to the area of your OverlapSphere and [zero out the lifetime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Particle-remainingLifetime.html) and/or kill the particle if it's within the area.
- If you have multiple colliders (and multiple emitters) per crop tile, determine which collider(s) have been intersected with. Within those colliders / each accompanying emitter, either:

  1. Iterate through each particle in the emitter, compare its position to the area of your OverlapSphere and zero out the lifetime and/or kill the particle if it's within the area.
  2. Potentially higher performance depending on how you've subdivided your crop tile colliders: kill all particles within the emitter. If you've subdivided your crop tile colliders into an 4x4 grid, for example, you only need to check for collision on - at most - 16 objects, but your crops will disappear in square chunks rather than by individual particles.

---

The idea here is to add one or more colliders (maybe 4, maybe 9, maybe 16) within each crop tile that correspond with event emitters. Use these colliders and emitters as a form of [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(image_processing)) to more cheaply collide with and control groups of particles rather than iterating through each particle individually.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. This helped me. :)